# How to defind the relationship between classes in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, associations

More specific about the question:
//There're two classes A and B:

```
Class A {
public static List<B> b = new ArrayList<B>();
}

Class B {
}
```

In my schema, I want to an object b from Class B. Then under all circumstances,object b will involve **at least two** objects "a_x" and "a_y" from Class A. How can I create such a relationship?

Answer (score 1):

First thing,This `public static List<B> b = new List<B>();`  wont compile.

You might need public `static List<B> b = new ArrayList<B>();`

You cannot instantiate an Interface.So provide an concreate implementation.`Ex:ArrayList`

And second thing,You should  add them directly where ever your are creating this `list`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relation where each `B` is related to *at least two* `A` instances, then `B` needs a collection-typed field.  For example:

```
   public class B {
       private List<A> relatedAList = new ArrayList<>();
       ...
   }
```

This needs to be an instance field, not a static field.

But if you have a `2+` relationship, it doesn't make sense to call the related objects `x` and `y` ... because what if there is a `z`, and a `p` and so on.  Unless there is a fixed upper bound on the number of related `A` objects for each `B`, you have to use some kind of collection to represent each `B`'s related `A`s.

Answer (score 0):

This is the relationship:

```
class A
{
    public List<B> b = new ArrayList<B>();
}

class B
{

    A ax;
    A ay;

    B(A ax, A ay)
    {
        this.ax = ax;
        this.ay = ay;
    }
}
```

This is what you need?

Why do you need such relantioship?